# Can you change the name of an element on an array without trying to set the names of the entire array?

Tags: r, arrays, names

I was recently surprised to find that the following didn't work:

```
output<-array(1:10)
names(output[1])<-"Foo"
```

As far as I can tell, this does not changes the name of `output[1]`. Is it possible to modify the names of the individual elements of an array like this? Or am I forced to write code that modifies the entire array, like `names(output)<-c("foo",rep(NA,9))`?

Comment: Maybe with `names(output)[1]<-"Foo"`??

Comment: @P.Paccioretti Huh. Neet.

Comment: @P.Paccioretti You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the first name of an element, so `[1]` goes outside `names(output)`:

```r
output<-array(1:10)
names(output)[1]<-"Foo"
names(output)
#>  [1] "Foo" NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```